# Laravel 4 Route::resource with multiple parameters

Tags: rest, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to have a REST design, but I am running in a bit of a problem. I have a resource `schedule`. Therefore, the normal notation of `/schedules/{id}` is not very applicable since I would like to have `/schedules/{day}/{month}/{year}` and then apply REST, and have `/edit` and such.

Is there a way to do this with `Route::resource()` ? or do I need to do them through `Route::get()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know route::resource only gives you the routes that are detailed in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) so for what you want you would need to declare your own route.  It is still restful and if it is only one of the resourceful routes you want to change you should still be able to do the following because the routes are prioritized in the order they are declared.

```
Route::get('schedule/{day}/{month}/{year}/edit', array('as' => 'editSchedule', 'uses' => 'ScheduleController@edit'));
Route::resource('schedule', 'ScheduleController');
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I were to extend this for all of the restful actions, I need to define each one through the code above right?

Comment: Yes but change get to whatever verb you want to use for the action

Comment: That's wrong. Laravel's resource can get multiple parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a very simple way. Here is an example:

Specify your route like this:

```
Route::resource("schedules/day.month.year", "ScheduleController");
```

The request will be like this:

```
/schedules/day/1/month/12/year/2014
```

And now you can get all three parameters in show method of your
    contoller:

```
public function show($day, $month, $year)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in `5.1`. Can you please provide source for your answer?

Comment: This solution only works with literal strings, not with route model binding.

Answer (score 2):

Hi there this might be handy if you want to call your route by name. Also you can use one or multiple parameters. It works with me on laravel 5.1

According to the laravel docs: 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', ['as' => 'profile', function ($id) {
    //
}]);

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

This works with Route:resource aswell.

for example:

```
Route::resource('{foo}/{bar}/dashboard', 'YourController');
```

Will create named routes like: `{foo}.{bar}.dashboard.show`

To call this with the route method, you set it up as followed.

```
route('{foo}.{bar}.dashboard.show', ['foo' => 1, 'bar'=> 2])
```

Which will create the url `yourdomain.com/1/2/dashboard`

Ill hope this is usefull.

Pascal